# Writing a method to read a binary file

Tags: java, classcastexception

I want to write a method that reads an object from a binary file but I want to generalize it using generics.

I have this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
public static <T> T readFromBinaryFile (String filename){
T obj = null;

if (FileUtils.existsFile (filename)){
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try{
        ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (filename));
        obj = (T)ois.readObject ();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Debug.out (e);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        Debug.out (e);
    }finally{
        try{
            if (ois != null) ois.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Debug.out (e);
        }
    }
}

return obj;

}
```

When I execute it I get a ClassCastException. I don't know anything about templates in java so any information will be apreciated. I've read something related to erasure, compile-time and execution-time but I don't understand very well why I get this ClassCastException.

Thanks.

EDIT: I call the method like this:
`FileUtils.readFromBinaryFile (filename);` (Without "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your method wrong. 
Just do it this way:

```
FileUtils.readFromBinaryFile (filename);
```

What you're calling is so-called generic method.

*"We don't have to pass an actual type argument to a generic method. The compiler infers the type argument for us, based on the types of the actual arguments. It will generally infer the most specific type argument that will make the call type-correct."* [source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

EDIT:

I've tried your example and it works (I had actually comment some lines)

```
    private static String filename = "number.serialized";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = 3.14;
        writeToBinary(d, filename);
        Double readD = readFromBinaryFile(filename);
        System.out.println(readD);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    public static <T> T readFromBinaryFile(String filename) {
        T obj = null;
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (file.exists()) {
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            try {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
                obj = (T)ois.readObject();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ois != null)
                        ois.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public static <T> void writeToBinary(T obj, String filename) 
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are there templates in Java?  Just use Object instead of T.  In Java everything derives from Object at the base, so you don't want T obj but Object obj.

Comment: Ok, there are templates in Java, but they use <>, as in public static <T> Entry<T,T> twice(T value)

Comment: Perhaps you mean Generics which are not like templates in C++

Answer (score 2):

A ClassCastException means the type you read didn't match the type you were expecting (and cast to) I suggest you see which object you are read in a debugger (or a log message) and compare it with what you are expecting.

Comment: The object I want to read it's ok. If I change T by MyObject (object saved to the file previously) I still get a ClassCastException.

Comment: Was the file you are reading created with ObjectOutputStream? That's one of the prereqs to using ObjectInputStream per the documentation. It isn't going to work on binary files created by anything not written in Java or even anything written in Java that didn't use ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: You also have to load the objects in order they were saved.

Comment: Yes, i save it with ObjectOutputStream. Also if I just copy the content of the method where I'm calling it, the code works well, but if a call the function then I get the exception.

Comment: I finally tried your code, but with String and Date.  It worked fine.